# Conditional subtraction of matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, subtraction

I am trying to do conditional subtraction of matrices in R. Let's say I have a list of matrices `A, B, C`. If my `selection = 1`, then `C = A - B`. Here are my codes:

```
selection = 1

A <- matrix(c(1:10), nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
A
B <- matrix(c(11:20), nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
B
C <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
C

my_matrix_name <- as.vector(c("A", "B", "C"))
my_list = list(A, B, C)
names(my_list) <- my_matrix_name

my_list$C <- ifelse(selection == 1, my_list$A - my_list$B, "Error")
```

The above codes yield the following results for `my_list`:

```
> my_list
$A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

$B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   16
[2,]   12   17
[3,]   13   18
[4,]   14   19
[5,]   15   20

$C
[1] -10
```

But my desired output is like this:

```
> my_list
$A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10

$B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   16
[2,]   12   17
[3,]   13   18
[4,]   14   19
[5,]   15   20

$C
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  -10  -10
[2,]  -10  -10
[3,]  -10  -10
[4,]  -10  -10
[5,]  -10  -10
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You are misusing `ifelse` and wouldn't be surprised if you had studied its documentation carefully. Use `if (...) ... else ...` instead,

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` since the condition that you are checking is scalar and not a vector.

```
my_list$C <- if(selection == 1) my_list$A - my_list$B else 'Error'
my_list

#$A
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]    2    7
#[3,]    3    8
#[4,]    4    9
#[5,]    5   10

#$B
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   11   16
#[2,]   12   17
#[3,]   13   18
#[4,]   14   19
#[5,]   15   20

#$C
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  -10  -10
#[2,]  -10  -10
#[3,]  -10  -10
#[4,]  -10  -10
#[5,]  -10  -10
```